# Is it possible to run two VPN clients at the same time?

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco

I would like to run two VPN clients at the same time: one Cisco client and one VPNC client. For now I have my VPNC client configured to route only some known IPs to the VNC interface and would like to add the same thing for the Cisco client at the same time. Is it possible ?

Do I need a Cisco client to connect to a Cisco server or can I use an other client such as VPNc ? I installed the cisco one because it was the one suggested but I am wondering if this is mandatory ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Of course you'll have to decide which IP goes through which. You seem to have already done that, so what's the question? What happens if you run both clients?

Comment: When launching the second client, the first one stop to work. It seems there is a conflict whith a resolve.conf file dynamically created. I was just asking to be sure before trying to figure out the right configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can run both at the same time. IIRC t is also possible to connect to a cisco concentrator using vpnc, as long as it has ipsec support. What will happen when you do both we can't tell. That depends on the VPN configurations, which may be pushed to your computer from the remote end.

To get what you want you probably have to manually configure your routing table to make sure only the correct traffic goes into the correct endpoint. There is no generic answer to this question though.

Comment: I was just asking to be sure before trying to figure out the right configuration.

Comment: vpnc is a lot more "cofiguration friedly". I'd suggest you try to make it work without the vpnclient

Comment: What happens depends on the IPSEC policy and the routing table of each. It's possible for both to be up and interoperable. It's also possible that each will try to take over the other. It really depends on the config of each one.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to install the 2nd vpn on a virtual machine(VM).  I could easily choose which VPN I wanted access without setting static routes (access the VM window to direct traffic to the 2nd VPN).